# Cannot include two subtemplates with Fat-Free framework

Tags: templates, fat-free-framework

I'm learning the Fat-Free framework and I came across an apparently simple problem: when I render a template I can use the `<include href="...">` directive to include a subtemplate **but that's it**, no more html gets parsed!

To be clear, suppose I have two html files, `main.html`:

```
<include href="sub.html">
STUFF
<include href="sub.html">
```

and, of course, `sub.html`:

```
<p>hello world</p>
```

now, I would expect the main template to render two subtemplates along with other STUFF, instead, the rendering stops after the first inclusion and no STUFF gets printed or anything whatsoever.

Am I getting something awfully wrong?

Comment: Check your UI config

Comment: `sub.html` should be in the same folder as `main.html`. If that's already the case, check PHP error log to get a clue of what's going on.